# Wrong encoding of emails

Tags: email, utf-8, character-encoding, polish

We can not figure out why two almost identical emails are differently rendered.

- One contains proper rendering of Polish characters:

[image]

In the Gmail source code, we can see:

`U=C5=BCyj linku poni=C5=BCej by zaakceptowa=C4=87 umow=C4=99 powie= rzenia danych osobowych`

- Another contains incorrect rendering of Polish characters:

[image]

In the Gmail source code, we can see:

`U=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BDyj linku poni=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BDej by zaakceptow= a=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD umow=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD powierzenia danych osobowych`

Encoding in both cases is defined as:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

From terminal, we can see that all the emails templates for command:

`$ file -bi *.html`

are returning:

`text/html; charset=utf-8`

What are we missing here?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, saving file again in Intellij IDE, rebuilding WAR file and deploying it on production solved this issue.

Comment: `EF BF BD` is the UTF-8 encoding of [U+FFFD `�` (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER)](https://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=65533), so the rendering is technically correct. You have to distinguish between what is _wrong_ and what you _don't want_.